# Error: P1017: Server has closed the connection

Tags: mysql, docker, nestjs, prisma

I was training on writing integration tests on a simple app and I had some of the working. After some errors I terminated the yarn command running the tests in watch mode and when restarting the same command I got the error in the object:

```
Error: P1017: Server has closed the connection
```

I am using prisma, nestjs and mySql as a database, containerized in docker.
I used a code from a tutorial as a base and that one works (it is identical to the following one except for the ports, since the tutorial is using postgres)

This it the docker-compose file

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  dev-db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    #platform: linux/amd64
    ports:
      - 3308:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123
      MYSQL_DB: dbfornest
  test-db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    #platform: linux/amd64
    ports:
      - 3305:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123
      MYSQL_DB: dbfornest
```

These are the scripts in the json file

```
 "db:restart": "docker compose down && docker compose up -d && sleep 1",
    "pretest:int": "yarn db:restart && dotenv -e .env.test -- prisma migrate reset --force",
    "test:int": "dotenv -e .env.test -- jest -i --no-cache --watch --config jest-int.json"
```

this is the .env file

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:123@localhost:3308/dbfornest
```

this is the .env.test file

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:123@localhost:3305/dbfornest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error was in the docker-compose file. The correct way of naming the database for mySQL is MYSQL_DATABASE